# Jquery Parse Error with Valid Json

Tags: php, json, jquery

I dont know why but I'm getting a Parse Error with valid JSON(I checked it on jsonlint).

I fetch data from a mysql db with php and make it a json string and retrive it to jquery(see the code below)

This is the jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "controller.php",
    data: {action:"loadObjs"},
    dataType: "json", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async:  true,
    success: function(objs){
            //do stuff
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        document.write(ajaxOptions);
        document.write(thrownError);
        docmuent.write(xhr);
    }
}
```

This is a section of controller.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
$action = $_GET['action'];

echo var_dump($action);

if ($action == "altaObj") {
    echo addObj();
} else if ($action == "bajaObj") {
//  delObj();
} else if ($action == "modObj") {
//  modObj();
} else if ($action == "loadObjs") {
    echo loadObjs();
} else if ($action == "loadObjProps") {

}
}

function loadObjs() {
$objs = Obj::GetAll();
return json_encode($objs);
}


?>
```

And this is GetAll() in Obj class:

```
public static function getAll(){            
    $return = array();
    try{
            $sql = "SELECT objectId, name FROM objs";
            $result = db::executeQuery($sql);
            while (false != ($r = mysql_fetch_object($result))) {
                $foo = new Obj($r->objectId, $r->name);
                //$foo->objectName = $r->objectName;
                $return[] = $foo;
            }
            return $return;
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the error ?

Comment: Can you show the actual JSON, especially the line where it is breaking? That would probably be more enlightening than the code that generates it

Comment: Can you post an example of the complete response from the PHP page? Just hit your url /controller.php?action=loadObjs and show us what its returning.

Comment: echo var_dump($action); <- makes invalid json. remove all other echos. and call the page manually

Comment: x4rf41 was rigth, I totally forgot about the var_dump. Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close, since the "Valid Json" bit proved wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It was the echo var_dump($action);

Thanks x4rf41